# C# / C++ DLL Debugging error: Unexpected symbol reader error while processing <file.dll>

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, visual-studio-2017

this is my situation:

- I'm currently debugging a c++ dll that is called from a C# desktop application.
- I'm able to step into the C++ code, however, I'm unable to get a step by step execution, especially in a for loop.
- Thinking this issue was related to compiler optimization I tried disabling it, but then the debugger throws the error "Unexpected symbol reader error while processing ".
- I'm working on VS Community 2017 Version 15.2
- I'm pretty new on C++ DLL development, this is code I didn't create and I'm trying to know how it works to implement some modifications.

Is there a way to do a step by step execution through the dll code?

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Have you rebuild the code after disabling optimizations?

Comment: Yeah, and I copied the .dll and the .pdb files into the debug directory.